# How to change folder permissions with java on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, file, netbeans, rxtx

I'm building a program that uses RXTX serial connection, the RXTX driver files need to be added in the /Library/Java/Extensions folder. To copy the drivers in the folder I first need to give a password before I can enter the paste function. Is there any way (maybe with a batch file) to copy my files in the protected folder? All the items on the internet shows the way to change the rights of the file not the folder.

I'm running MacOS 10.13.4 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want  to change the folder permission with java as the title implies I think you can follow the sample from https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-the-file-permission-in-java since a File object can also represent an directory.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and you can try using chmod.

Eg: chmod 755 foldername changes the permissions of the folder to rwxr-xr-x

Basically 755 is converted into binary and corresponding permission flag is set.